# How to await the same object from multiple asyncio tasks?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I have a number of tasks that work with session objects. As this sessions can be the same for multiple tasks I am trying to create some from of caching. Tasks request a session by name and it will only be created (which is costly) when it doesn't already exists.

What is the proper way to go about this with `asyncio`? Especially regarding saftiy in the parallelization context?

Do I require Locks or are Futurs already safe?

My fists attempt simply used a global `dict` to store the name and session. However this leads to problems: the session is only written to the cache **after its created**, which leaves a quite big time-span where the same session can be scheduled for creation again.

My second attempt stored the coroutine object in the global dict. I thought I can just await the coroutine from multiple places but doesn't work.

My current solution uses a future, which seems to work. Here is a mockup:

```py
import asyncio
import random
from asyncio import Future

DATA: dict[str, Future] = dict()

def get_data(name) -> Future:
    global DATA
    if name not in DATA:
        future = Future()
        DATA[name] = future
        asyncio.create_task( costly(future) )
    return DATA[name]

async def task(i):
    print("task", i, "started")
    d = await get_data("a")
    print("task", i, d)

async def costly(future: Future) -> bool:
    print("beginning costly")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("costly is done")
    future.set_result(str(random.random()))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(task(i)) for i in range(0,3)])
    await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(task(i)) for i in range(3,5)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However I am not sure if this approach is proper and if it can lead to any problem? Are there caveats I should be aware of? Or is there a different approach I am not aware of?